# Get Following Error,When I Run Selenium Command From Terminals

Tags: selenium

When I run selenium command on terminal i.e ant test selenium-ui-functional.
I get following Errors

```
[javac] /home/jbilling/jbilling-4/enterprise/test/functional/com/sapienter/jbilling/selenium/sanity/JBillingSanityTest.java:15: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
    [javac] import org.openqa.selenium.*;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] /home/jbilling/jbilling-4/enterprise/test/functional/com/sapienter/jbilling/selenium/sanity/JBillingSanityTest.java:16: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
    [javac] import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    [javac]                           ^
    [javac] /home/jbilling/jbilling-4/enterprise/test/functional/com/sapienter/jbilling/selenium/sanity/JBillingSanityTest.java:17: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
    [javac] import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
    [javac]                           ^
    [javac] /home/jbilling/jbilling-4/enterprise/test/functional/com/sapienter/jbilling/selenium/sanity/JBillingSanityTest.java:18: package org.openqa.selenium.firefox does not exist
    [javac] import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /home/jbilling/jbilling-4/enterprise/test/functional/com/sapienter/jbilling/selenium/sanity/JBillingSanityTest.java:19: package org.openqa.selenium.support.ui does not exist
    [javac] import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
    [javac]                                      ^
    [javac] /home/jbilling/jbilling-4/enterprise/test/functional/com/sapienter/jbilling/selenium/sanity/JBillingSanityTest.java:24: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class WebDriver
    [javac] location: class com.sapienter.jbilling.selenium.sanity.JBillingSanityTest
    [javac]   private WebDriver driver;
    [javac]           ^
    [javac] /home/jbilling/jbilling-4/enterprise/test/functional/com/sapienter/jbilling/selenium/sanity/JBillingSanityTest.java:31: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class FirefoxDriver
    [javac] location: class com.sapienter.jbilling.selenium.sanity.JBillingSanityTest
    [javac]     driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] /home/jbilling/jbilling-4/enterprise/test/functional/com/sapienter/jbilling/server/payment/WSTest.java:317: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable STATUS_SUSPENDED
    [javac] location: class com.sapienter.jbilling.server.user.UserDTOEx
    [javac]             user.setStatusId(UserDTOEx.STATUS_SUSPENDED);
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] 8 errors

BUILD FAILED
/home/jbilling/jbilling-4/enterprise/build.xml:122: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/jbilling/jbilling-4/enterprise/build.xml:185: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 12 seconds
```

I have inserted selenium-java-2.40.0.jar,selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar inside testlib folder.

Please,can anybody tell me solution for this issue?

Comment: your question is almost unreadble.  please use the formatting options to improve this.

Comment: Make sure the jars are on classpath

Comment: Hello @karna all jars are on classpath

Answer (score 0):

This *looks* like maven, but you haven't tagged it as such.  (If it isn't, I will delete / edit this question)

You need to make sure that your `selenium-java` / `selenium-api` dependency has the proper [`<scope>...</scope>`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)

Answer (score -1):

```
javac -cp "C:\selenium-2.42.2\selenium-java-2.42.2.jar;selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.j‌​‌​ar" Test.java 

java -cp "C:\selenium-2.42.2\selenium-java-2.42.2.jar;.;selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2‌​‌​.jar" Test
```

Test is java file name